# how to get the rendered HTML element from the screen, from react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

IN the react testing library, I want to get the entire rendered HTML, from the screen and check if this rendered correctly and is present in the dom.

I see that the screen has the methods to query the DOM, but how to access full HTML which is rendered.

```
import React from 'react';
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import {server} from '../__mock__/server.mock';
import InfoBar from '../Components/infoBar';

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());

test('InfoBar renders correctly.', async () => {
    render(<InfoBar/>);
    expect(screen).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

`expect(screen).toBeInTheDocument();` this doesnt work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get entire HTML, you can try using

```js
const { container } = render(<InfoBar />);
expect(container).toMatchSnapshot()
```

This will save a snapshot file, which you can review.

Or to get the snapshot of HTML there and there itself, you can use:

```js
expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot()
```

and then run test, which will then fill brackets of `toMatchInlineSnapshot()` with the HTML like so:

```js
expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
  <div>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
`)
```

For more, refer here: [Snapshot Testing](https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing)